# How to call another method while first method is in running state

Tags: c#, multithreading, console-application

I am developing a console application in which two methods `start` and `stop` are written. When the `start` method is called it starts capturing audio data from the system and remains in working state and console is stuck at one point. Now I want to call the `stop` method to stop the `start` method, but console is still stuck on the `start` method. I try to call stop method from another console but it fails: *"Unhandled Exception: System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object."*
How could I achieve this?

First I want to call `wavtomp3` and while its working I want to call `stoprecording()` from the console app.
Here is my code:

```
    static LameMP3FileWriter wri;
    static IWaveIn waveIn;

    public void wavtomp3(string fName,string storageLocation)
    {

        string[] aFileName=fName.Split('.');
        aFileName[0] = aFileName[0] + ".mp3";
        string aSaveLocation = storageLocation + "\\"+aFileName[0];

       // MessageBox.Show("Sample Rate=" + waveIn.WaveFormat.SampleRate.ToString());
       // string fname = DateTime.Now.Ticks.ToString();

        // Start recording from loopback
        waveIn = new WasapiLoopbackCapture();
        wri = new LameMP3FileWriter(aSaveLocation, waveIn.WaveFormat, 44);
        waveIn.DataAvailable += waveIn_DataAvailable;
        waveIn.RecordingStopped += waveIn_RecordingStopped;
        waveIn.StartRecording();
    }

    static void waveIn_RecordingStopped(object sender, StoppedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (waveIn != null) // working around problem with double raising of RecordingStopped
        {
            waveIn.Dispose();
            waveIn = null;
        }
        if (wri != null)
        {
            wri.Close();
            wri = null;
        }

    }

    static void waveIn_DataAvailable(object sender, WaveInEventArgs e)
    {
        if (wri != null)

            if (e.BytesRecorded == 0)
            {
                wri.Write(e.Buffer, 0, 12800);
                Debug.WriteLine("Adding Silence To File No Sound is playing");
            }
            else if (e.BytesRecorded > 0)
            {
                wri.Write(e.Buffer, 0, e.BytesRecorded);
                Debug.WriteLine("Sound Playing From Sound Card and recording");
            }

        Debug.WriteLine("bytes record=" + e.BytesRecorded);

    }

    public void stoprecording()
    {

        waveIn.StopRecording();
        Debug.WriteLine("StopRecording");

    }
```

Comment: You've posted your question with the **multithreading** tag so you know what to do :) run your "start" method in a new thread and make the main thread wait with a simple `Console.ReadLine`. The reason why using a second console application does not work is because the two processes does not share any state so they can't communicate this way, you've just created another image of your program with data not initialized, hence the `NullReferenceException`.

Comment: Hi Pragmateek 
I try to do this I put main function in thread but not user console.readline should I call stop method by thread . any working code thanks for help.

Comment: `waveIn.StartRecording();` does not block program execution.